# Can I display and update a form with no user interaction required?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a C# WinForms program that must bring up a form, and then automatically launch into a method that regularly updates a log box (rich text box) on the form - with no user interaction required (or allowed).

This would be easy if I could simply provide button for the user to click to launch the process (method call).  But that is not possible.  The requirements state that the process must start automatically, with no user interaction, because of timing issues.

I tried to do this in the Form Load event handler, but the form itself is not displayed until that handler is done.

Can I somehow create an invisible button on the form and "schedule" click event to occur upon display of the form?

Comment: Override the OnShown method.  Otherwise, your question is a bit vague what help you are looking for.

Comment: Question is a bit vague. I'd use a timer control set by default to enabled = true and just to RichTextBox1.Update() If you didn't want this to repeat for infinity, you could define a variable at the top of the class and each time the timer ticks add one to the counter, and add a piece of code at the start of the timer sub that checks the counter is below the number you want. Otherwise, I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Drag/Drop a timer control onto your form.
2. Hook up the events shown below (Shown, FormClosing, and the timer's Tick).
3. Copy/paste the code shown below and then run the program.

The form will be displayed and then automatically updated every 5 seconds by whatever code you decide to put inside the UpdateForm() method - for example changing the text displayed in a TextBox, RichTextBox or whatever you need.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The interval is specified in milliseconds, so 5000 is 5 seconds.  Change as required.
        timer1.Interval = 5000; 
        timer1.Start();
        //timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateForm();
    }

    private void UpdateForm()
    {
        // Do some work
        // Console.WriteLine("UpdateForm() method was called.");
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pipalot - this worked.